# Does Dust.js provide a way to reference an object key/value by keywords "key" and "value"?

Tags: dust.js

I want to use Dust.js as a client template engine.
I have a data json like this:

```
var data = {
    "Foo": [{
        "somekey": "somevalue",
        "otherkey": "othervalue"
    }, {
        "somekey": "somevalue",
        "otherkey": "othervalue"
    }],
    "Bar": [{
        "somekey": "somevalue",
        "otherkey": "othervalue"
    }, {
        "somekey": "somevalue",
        "otherkey": "othervalue"
    }]
}
```

I do not know in advance what uppermost object keys will be - I do not know `Foo` and `Bar` keys, they can be any value.

So, I need to iterate through this json by keywords like `key` and `value`. Something like in this pseudo-code:

```
{% for(key, value) in data %}
   {key}: {value}
{% /for %}
```

I know that Dust.js has `{#section/}` to loop through an object. But again, you have to provide a key name:

```
{#extraData}
  {!
    Inside this section, Dust looks for
    values within the extraData object
  !}
  Inside the section, the value of name is: {name}{~n}
{/extraData}
```

And I do not know `extraData` name in advance.

So, does Dust.js provide a way to reference object keys/values by `key` and `value` keywords?

Comment: @SwarajGiri, no, unfortunately doesn't work. But it doesn't break the code either. All works fine. `this.key` is the same as `{.}`

Answer (score 2):

Dust does not provide built-in iteration over objects.

However, you can add the `{@iterate}` helper to do this type of iteration.

You can get it at https://www.npmjs.com/package/dustmotes-iterate

Example usage:

```
      Data: { obj: {a:"A", b:"B", c:"C" } }

      {@iterate key=obj}
        {$key}:{$value} {$type}
      {/iterate}

      Output: a:A string b:B string c:C string
```